# How to change values of input fields that match data attribute value with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to change the input fields value for every matching element with a certain data attribute value. 
So a user clicks a value, and the input fields appears, and then the amount entered into the input field is also reflected in the other fields with the same productid.

i.e Change cost price on Parent product, and the Variation is also updated live.

The Code.

HTML

```
<table>

<tr>
    <td>Product One</td>
    <td>
        <p class="cost" data-productid="107">12.00</p>
        <input type="text" style="display:none" class="cost_input" data-productid="107"/>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Variation of Product One</td>
    <td>
        <p class="cost">12.00</p>
        <input type="text" style="display:none" class="cost_input 107" data-productid="107"/>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Product Two</td>
    <td>
        <p class="cost" data-productid="108">12.00</p>
        <input type="text" style="display:none" class="cost_input" data-productid="108"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

JS

```
    $(".cost").click(function(event) {
            var id = $(this).data('productid');
            $(".cost").hide();
            $('.cost_input').show();
            $(this).next().select();            
            $('.cost_input [data-productid="'+id+'"]').bind('keyup keypress blur', function() {  
            $('.cost_input [data-productid="'+id+'"]').val($(this).val());
            });
});
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ez4uD/15/

Comment: why on earth would this get a negative vote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty close, just get rid of the space in your selector between `input` and `[data`

```
$('.cost_input[data-productid="'+id+'"]')
```

Comment: Right. The space implies a child relationship. You don't want that.